# password_verify - password doesn't matches the hash

Tags: php

I have a login system. You can sign up a user and login later (in this case password_verify does its job). Then I have a pwd recovery system. You are sent an e-mail with a link with token and so on. You change your password and it is changed in the database (as I can see it by changed hash). Then if you try to login with a new password it says wrong pwd, neither does the old password.

```
/// new password is set
$newPwdHash = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $newPwdHash, $tokenEmail);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$pwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['pwdUsers']);
```

I don't know if it helps, but if u try to set not a hashed pwd but a usual one when u are recovering the pwd, it changes it in the database as an empty blank idk why.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

```
//login
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    require 'db.inc.php';
    $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];    
    if (empty($mailuid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=empty');
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?';
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header('Location: ../index.php?error=sql');
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $mailuid, $mailuid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $pwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['pwdUsers']);
                if (!$pwdCheck) {
                    header('Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwdormail');
                    exit();
                } elseif ($pwdCheck) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['idUsers'];
                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uidUsers'];
                    header('Location: ../index.php?login=success');
                    exit();
                } else {
                    header('Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwdormail');
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                header('Location: ../index.php?error=nouser');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit();
}

//reset
$tokenEmail = $row['pwdResetEmail'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailUsers=?';
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo 'error2';
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $tokenEmail);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo 'error3';
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET pwdUsers=? WHERE emailUsers=?';
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo 'error4';
            exit();
        } else {
            $newPwdHash = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $newPwdHash, $tokenEmail);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM pwdReset WHERE pwdResetEmail=?';
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo 'error5';
                exit();
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $tokenEmail);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                header('Location: ../signup.php?newpwd=updated');
           }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: maybe $pwd is not what you think it is, maybe its hashing undefined etc its still going to produce a hash, https://3v4l.org/DXUmo enable error reporting, please show relevant code

Comment: how can it be undefined if i had already checked it in all cases, what's more it works in usual case

Comment: pwdCheck shows false when I update the password and try to login

Comment: `it changes it in the database as an empty blank idk why` is something you need to figure out. You can't just have values changing in the DB. Please show the table definition, how you are inserting the hash, and how you are retrieving the user (`$row`).

Comment: it is set to longtext

Comment: What do you get for outputting when executing?

Answer (score 0):

NOTICE: unless you are duplicating the variables on multiple parts
            included OUTSIDE of the login (isset) part, it most likely is undefined
            thus, hashing an undefined variable. So the password will NEVER match.

Notice how you are using a variable `$pwd` in the reset part, even though you are creating the `$pwd` variable within the "login" part. I highly doubt you are even reaching that part if both parts of code are included in one file and the order is in the order you posted on StackOverflow.

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
        $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
        //NOTICE: unless you are duplicating the variables on multiple parts
        //including OUTSIDE of the login (isset) part, it most likely is undefined
        //thus, hashing an undefined variable. So the password will NEVER match.
} else {
    //header('Location: ../index.php');
    //exit(); //will halt execute, so it's interesting that you're even reaching the reset part. 
    //Unless the reset part and login part aren't in the same file.
}
```

Are both the reset part and the login part in the same file?

```
else {
            $newPwdHash = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $newPwdHash, $tokenEmail);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM pwdReset WHERE pwdResetEmail=?';
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo 'error5';
                exit();
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $tokenEmail);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                header('Location: ../signup.php?newpwd=updated');
           }
        }
```

I recommend you create a dedicated page for the reset part, where you can do something along the lines of:

```
if (isset($_POST["recovery"])) { // or whatever kind of check you wish to do prior to firing your code.
$tokenEmail = $row['pwdResetEmail']; //no idea where you created this -> 
//$row["pwdResetEmail"]; I assume it's a part you're either not showing us, 
//or this isn't working either. I am guessing the first one (that you aren't 
//showing us where you retrieve it), or else it would not be possible to 
//change anything and the query should fail (correct me if I am wrong here guys).
$pwd = // NOTICE: assign the password. May it be a POST or a GET or whatever
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailUsers=?';
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo 'error2';
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $tokenEmail);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo 'error3';
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = 'UPDATE users SET pwdUsers=? WHERE emailUsers=?';
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo 'error4';
            exit();
        } else {
            $newPwdHash = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //NOTICE: 
            //NOW THE VARIABLE $PWD IS DEFINED
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $newPwdHash, $tokenEmail);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM pwdReset WHERE pwdResetEmail=?';
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo 'error5';
                exit();
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $tokenEmail);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                header('Location: ../signup.php?newpwd=updated');
           }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

KK, i made a debugging and here is what i found: when i required db.php file there was a variable named $pwd which was empty that's why there was no value when i was trying to set new pwd.